# kivy: how can i have a recycleview display data unique to that instance

Tags: python, kivy

i have two instances of a recycleview managed buy a screen manager, but im struggling to have each instance display its unique data. they seem to share the data attribute. when i add a button to 'screen1' it shows up under 'screen2' instance as well. how do i direct the current instance to use the data unique to it? any help aprreciated thanks.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager
from kivy.uix.recycleview import RecycleView
from kivy.uix.recycleview.views import RecycleDataViewBehavior
from kivy.uix.button import Button


kv = """
<ViewList>:
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1
        Rectangle:
            size: self.size
            pos: self.pos
    text: self.value

    InputScreen:
        name: 'input_screen'
        id: inputscreen

    MyReusableScreen:
        name: 'screen1'
        id: screen1

    MyReusableScreen:
        name: 'screen2'
        id: screen2


<InputScreen>:
    name: 'input_screen'

    orientation: "vertical"
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"

        Button:
            text: "first screen"
            on_press: root.manager.current = 'screen1'

        Button:
            text: 'second screen'
            on_press: root.manager.current = 'screen2'


<MyReusableScreen>:
    name: 'mrs'
    rv: rv
    orientation: "vertical"
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"

        Label:
            text: root.name

        Button:

            text: "add"
            on_press: app.add_data('text')

        Button:

            text: "input screen"
            on_press: root.manager.current = 'input_screen'

        RV:
            id: rv
            viewclass: 'ViewList'
            RecycleBoxLayout:
                default_size: None, dp(56)
                default_size_hint: 1, None
                size_hint_y: None
                height: self.minimum_height
                orientation: 'vertical'

"""

Builder.load_string(kv)


class ViewList(RecycleDataViewBehavior, Button):
    def refresh_view_attrs(self, rv, index, data):
        self.index = index
        return super(ViewList, self).refresh_view_attrs(
            rv, index, data)


class RV(RecycleView):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(RV, self).__init__(**kwargs)


class Root(ScreenManager):
    pass


class MyReusableScreen(Screen):
    def __init__(self, ** kwargs):
        super(MyReusableScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)


class InputScreen(Screen):
    pass


class TestApp(App):

    def build(self):

        return Root()

    def add_data(self, value):
        sc = self.root.get_screen('screen1')
        sc.ids.rv.data.insert(0, {'value': value} or 'default 1')
        sc2 = self.root.get_screen('screen2')
        sc2.ids.rv.data.insert(0, {'value': value or 'default 2'})

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

Comment: It looks like your `add_data()` method is adding the same data to both `RecycleViews`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I adjusted some things to make your example run. First of all I added some things in your build method to see your InputScreen when the programm starts. Then I removed the value part, because for demonstration purposes it is only neccessary to see the switching default number when you switch between your screens. It looked like this:

```
class TestApp(App):

    def build(self):
        root = Root()
        root.add_widget(InputScreen())
        screen1 = MyReusableScreen(name='screen1')
        screen2 = MyReusableScreen(name='screen2')
        root.add_widget(screen1)
        root.add_widget(screen2)
        root.current = "input_screen"
        return root

    def add_data(self, value):
        sc = self.root.get_screen('screen1')
        sc.ids.rv.data.insert(0, {'value': 'default 1'})
        sc2 = self.root.get_screen('screen2')
        sc2.ids.rv.data.insert(0, {'value': 'default 2'})
```

And now the important part. You have to set a property in your viewclass in order to use the data value. As it is a string a StringProperty is what we are looking for. It should look like this.

```
class ViewList(RecycleDataViewBehavior, Button):
    value = StringProperty("")
```

Another way would be to use the refresh_view_attrs method and set the button text to your new data. But then you have to change your initial kv string as self.value does not exist then.

KV

```
<ViewList>:
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1
        Rectangle:
            size: self.size
            pos: self.pos
    text: ""
```

Python

```
class ViewList(RecycleDataViewBehavior, Button):

    def refresh_view_attrs(self, rv, index, data):
        self.index = index
        self.text = data['value']
        return super(ViewList, self).refresh_view_attrs(
            rv, index, data)
```

Comment: thank you for clarifying. i noticed that if i declare the value in the .kv file for viewlist it also works with out assigning it under a ViewList class in the .py file.  is that because kivy knows tho assign value: the property of 'StringProperty'? is there drawbacks to doing it on the .kv file side?